# Comparable in java for C#'s DateTime.ToFileTimeUTC?

Tags: java, c#

I have a program that I am converting from C# to Java and have run into a strange issue:

The C# application outputs a 'windows timestamp' via the following code:

```
private static readonly DateTime epochDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
double totalSeconds = seconds + nanosecs / 1000000000.0;
wintimestamp = epochDateTime.AddSeconds(totalSeconds).ToFileTimeUtc();
```

I'm having trouble trying to duplicate the functionality of "ToFileTimeUtc" in Java. I need to keep it since the existing applications that use the data generated from this application are expecting the same data format.

I have tried some this in java and got it to match up. But I would like a deeper explanation as to what I'm doing.

```
     int second = 1589913034;
    int nanosec = 24;
    double totalSeconds = second + nanosec / 1_000_000_000.0;
    System.out.println(totalSeconds);
    long wintimestamp = (long) (116444736000000000L + totalSeconds * 10_000_000);
    System.out.println(wintimestamp);
```

I'm pretty sure this value: 116444736000000000L is the epoch equivalence of the 1601 Win32 epoch to the regular java epoch. I got this from doing:

```
 epochDateTime.AddSeconds(totalSeconds).ToFileTimeUtc();
```

Then I finally started playing around with the multiplier until I got close to the value from the C# call finally landing on 10 million that got me the exact same number. Not sure why though.

Comment: First, go with the Java 8 Time API.

Comment: I was just playing around in a test class trying to replicate. I'll use time in the end.

Answer (score 1):

If you **read the documentation** of [`DateTime.ToFileTimeUtc()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tofiletimeutc?view=netcore-3.1) you will find:

> A Windows file time is a 64-bit value that represents the number of **100-nanosecond** intervals that have elapsed since 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.) Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

100-nanoseconds is 1 / 10_000_000 seconds.

Comment: Thank you! I was just arriving at that same conclusion and popped back to this question to answer it myself.